# Problems with uploading file using Vue.js and Laravel

Tags: php, laravel, file, vue.js, file-upload

Vue template (File upload): This input field is generated from another module, Where the from generated by drag and drop input field.

```
<input type="file" @change="uploadFile(data,$event)" class="custom-file-input" id="validatedCustomFile">
```

Script Vuejs:

```
data () {
    return {
        //baseform
        baseForm: new Form({
            form:this.data ? JSON.parse(this.data.dataForm) : '',
        }),
    }
},


methods: {

    uploadFile(data,e){
        let file = e.target.files[0];
        data.value = file;
    },

    // form data submit
    formSubmit() {
      const config = {
        headers: {'Content-Type': 'multipart/form-data'}
      }

      let formData = new FormData();
      formData.append('form',JSON.stringify(this.baseForm.form));
      axios.post('/api/order-data',formData, config)
        .then((order)=>{
            //
        }).catch(()=>{
            //
        })
    }
}
```

[image]

Controller: Here is the controller code

```
    $formData = json_decode($request->form, true);
    foreach ($formData as $key) {
        if($key['field'] == 'fileUpload') {
            dd($key['value']);
        }
    }
```

I am getting empty value after die dump $key['value']

Comment: This is due to the fact that `file` elemeuploadsnts do not appear in the `request `array but rather in the `$_FILES` array. try `$request->file('fileUpload')`.

Comment: Here fileUpload is label name. The file details stored in $key['value']. I have attached a screenshot.

Comment: Just because you've constructed it in this way does not mean that you change the specification for posting files.

Comment: so how can I do this? or what is the best way to do this?
Note: The file filed can be increased based on user demand.

Comment: Maybe you can just use `foreach($request->all() as $key => $value)` and `is_file($value)`?